# Send Image (jpg/png) as an attachment to mail | UTL_MAIL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, email-attachments, utl-mail

I am stuck not getting how do I send mail with Image as an attachment via `UTL_MAIL`

I am uploading the attachment to below table via **ORACLE APEX 20.x**

**Table :** `my_attachment`

```
create table my_attachment
(
    my_file_clob blob,
    mimetype varchar2(255 char),
    file_name varchar2(255 char),
    created_date date 
);
```

**My code :**

```
DECLARE

    my_file_name VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);
    my_mime_type VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);
    
BEGIN
    SELECT
        fname
    INTO my_file_name
    FROM
        my_attachment
    WHERE
        create_date = '12-FEB-22';

    SELECT
        fmime
    INTO my_mime_type
    FROM
        my_attachment
    WHERE
        create_date = '12-FEB-22';

    sys.utl_mail.send_attach_varchar2(
    
    sender => 'xyz.outlook.com',
    subject => 'Testing image attachment', 
    message => 'Hi All checking Image attachment', 
    mime_type => my_mime_type, 
    att_file_name => my_file_name);

END;
```

**Error :**

```
ORA-06550 : line 15, column 3:
PLS-00306 : wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'send_attach_varchar2'
*Cause     : Compliation error 
*Action
```

Comment: you are missing at least this one:
attachment        IN    RAW,

more detail: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm#i1001008

Comment: Using (local) date strings and even only 2-digit year is always a bad idea.